# React JS 'a' Tag Does Not Direct To New Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am dealing with a new issue where the two buttons below will not direct to a new page. It was originally working, but now it is not working... I have added the code for the two pages, App.js and AdminTool.js. I noticed that when the buttons are pressed, a "?" mark is added at the end of the URL instead of redirecting. The code has been uploaded to codesandbox.io https://codesandbox.io/s/bible-trivia-rebuild-8q54zd

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
//Basics
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login';
import Logout from './Pages/Logout/Logout';
import Register from './Pages/Register/Register';
import AccountVerification from './Pages/AccountVerification/AccountVerification';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile/Profile';
import ProfileUpdate from './Pages/ProfileUpdate/ProfileUpdate';
import ProfileDelete from './Pages/ProfileDelete/ProfileDelete';
import Dashboard from './Pages/Dashboard/Dashboard';
//Admin
import AdminTools from './Pages/AdminTools/AdminTools';
import AdminToolsVerification from './Pages/AdminToolsVerification/AdminToolsVerification';
import AdminToolsManageAccount from './Pages/AdminToolsManageAccount/AdminToolsManageAccount';
import AdminToolsManageAccountAdd from './Pages/AdminToolsManageAccountAdd/AdminToolsManageAccountAdd';
import AdminToolsManageAccountDelete from './Pages/AdminToolsManageAccountDelete/AdminToolsManageAccountDelete';
import AdminToolsManageAccountDetail from './Pages/AdminToolsManageAccountDetail/AdminToolsManageAccountDetail';
import AdminToolsManageAccountUpdate from './Pages/AdminToolsManageAccountUpdate/AdminToolsManageAccountUpdate';
import AdminToolsManageTrivia from './Pages/AdminToolsManageTrivia/AdminToolsManageTrivia';
//Game Page
import LevelChoice from './Pages/LevelChoice/LevelChoice';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Dashboard/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/Register' element={<Register/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/Login' element={<Login/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/Logout' element={<Logout/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/AccountVerification/:AccountUsername' element={<AccountVerification/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/Profile/:AccountUsername' element={<Profile/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/Profile/:AccountUsername/Delete' element={<ProfileDelete/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/Profile/:AccountUsername/Update' element={<ProfileUpdate/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/LevelChoice' element={<LevelChoice/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools' element={<AdminTools/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts' element={<AdminToolsManageAccount/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts/Verification' element={<AdminToolsVerification/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts/AddAdmin' element={<AdminToolsManageAccountAdd/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts/:SelectedAdmin/Delete' element={<AdminToolsManageAccountDelete/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts/:SelectedAdmin/Detail' element={<AdminToolsManageAccountDetail/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts/:SelectedAdmin/Update' element={<AdminToolsManageAccountUpdate/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions' element={<AdminToolsManageTrivia/>} />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions/AddQuestion' />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions/:QuestionID/Detail' />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions/:QuestionID/Delete' />;
          <Route exact path='/:AccountUsername/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions/:QuestionID/Update' />;
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AdminTools.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './AdminTools.css';
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Functions
import CheckLogin from '../../Functions/VerificationCheck/checkLogin';
import CheckUser from '../../Functions/VerificationCheck/checkUser';
import GetUserVerification from '../../Functions/VerificationCheck/getLogoutStatus';
import GetAdminRole from '../../Functions/VerificationCheck/getAdminRole';
//Repositories
import { useNavigate, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const AdminTools = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const {AccountUsername} = useParams();
    const userLoggedIn = CheckLogin();
    const loggedInUser = CheckUser(userLoggedIn);
    const logOutStatus = GetUserVerification(AccountUsername);
    const isAdmin = GetAdminRole();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!userLoggedIn) {
            navigate('/Login', {
                state: {
                    previousUrl: location.pathname,
                }
            });
        }
        else if (logOutStatus) {
            navigate('/Logout');
        }
        else if (!isAdmin) {
            navigate('/');
        }
    }, [userLoggedIn]);
    
    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            {isLoading ?
                <div className='page_container'>
                    <form className='adminTools_form'>
                        <h1>Loading...</h1>
                    </form>
                </div>
                :            
                <div className='page_container'>
                    <form className='adminTools_form'>
                        <h1>Pick A Tool</h1>
                        <a href={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts`}><button className='adminToolsButton'>Manage Admin Accounts</button></a>
                        <a href={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions`}><button className='adminToolsButton'>Manage Trivia Questions</button></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            }
            <Footer/>
        </>
    );
}

export default AdminTools;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for my bad english.
This error is due to the fact that you are using a button element inside an a element, you can solve this in several ways:

**Way 1**:
Place the entire button element style in the anchor element and remove the button.

```
.adminTools_form > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 3em;
  width: 18em;
  margin: 1em auto 1.5em auto;
  border: 0.15em solid purple;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.adminTools_form > a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
  border: 0.15em solid darkgoldenrod;
}


<a href={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions`}>
  Manage Trivia Questions
</a>
```

**Way 2**:
Change the button tag to a div, span or something

```
<a href={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts`}>
  <div className="adminToolsButton">
    Manage Admin Accounts
  </div>
</a>
<a href={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions`}>
  <div className="adminToolsButton">
    Manage Trivia Questions
  </div>
</a>
```

**Way 3**: (recommended):
Try to use the Link component that react-router-dom gives you, in addition to giving you many benefits you could use the idea of ​​the SPA (Single Page Application), to know how to use it visit this link: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link

```
// import the Link component
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Link to={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageAdminAccounts`}>
  <button className="adminToolsButton">
    Manage Admin Accounts
  </button>
</Link>
<Link to={`/${loggedInUser}/AdminTools/ManageTriviaQuestions`}>
  <button className="adminToolsButton">
    Manage Trivia Questions
  </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks for the various choices, I went with the recommended one, and it worked!

Comment: You're welcome, thank you, my first reply :)